# If I set something in the controller, how do I access it in the view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created this in a the company controller.

```
$scope.$watch('companyName', function () {
      console.log($scope.company.name); 
    });
```

I wanted to get the company name, how do I call it where the `ng-controller` matches the controller name in the view?

Would it be something along the lines of this?

```
<span ng-init="companyName"> {{ companyName() }} </span>
```

I'm not sure I understand how to get the information from that function in the view. I think I've confused myself.

Comment: Upvotes for everybody!!! All are correct

Comment: Yes! Everyone's been incredibly helpful today. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have confused yourself!

In the company controller all you need to do is:

```
$scope.companyName = "ACME";
```

To access it in the view:

```
{{ companyName }}
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, your sample seems *a bit* strange.

Anyway, to bind a `$scope` property in the view, you use its name.

So in the controller:

```
$scope.company = { name: "Acme" };
```

And in the view:

```
<span> {{ company.name }} </span>
```

There is no need to create a `$watch` manually.  Angular will create a watch for any property used in the view (for you).

You also, don't have to use `ng-init`, unless you want to initialize something in the view.

To see the watch in action, simple add a text `input` next to the `span`:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="company.name"/>
```

If you change the value in the text box, you will see the changes reflected in the `span`.

[Here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tqWTIy?p=preview) to play with that demonstrates.

Answer (score 2):

When binding to values, it is assumed to be relative to `$scope`. In this case (assuming the value you want is the same as what you specify in your `$watch`), you want to `init` an item to an object, and it should look something like this:

```
 <span ng-init="company = {name: 'whatever' }">{{company.name}}</span>
```

For various reasons, it's not recommended to use `ng-init` except in things like `ng-repeat`. If it works, it works, but I'd recommend getting used to initializing things in your controller (just add the statement, such as `$scope.company = {name: 'whatever'};` somewhere before your controller function ends). One reason is to make it easier to test your controller in unit tests, because it's annoying to make your tests dependent on a particular view).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest was to do it:

controller:

```
$scope.companyName = "My company";
```

view:

```
<span>{{companyName}}</span>
```

`$scope.$watch` is just a function to monitor changes in the value of CompanyName, I don't think you need it.